# How to set up control for case fans in Debian Wheezy?

Tags: acpi, debian, fan

We'll for some days now I've been trying to get the fancontrol for my Debian Wheezy up and running. Actually (after some problems with pwmconfig not accepting my chipset, which is a AMD 770 one) now at least CPU and GFC-card fans are being controlled by fancontrol. But, this being already a very nice success, I was wondering how to control (specifically, lower) the speed (and the volume therefore) of my case fans? I've to admit I have absolutely no clue where to begin? (I only know that it should be possible somehow, because Ubuntu 12.04 did it.. but I am currently all in favor of Debian, so it would be quite nice to have this ability there as well.)

So, I would really appreciate any kind of help with this issue.

Here's some basic information about my system:

```
CPU: AMD Athlon64 5050e
GFX: MSI NX7800GT (nV 7800GT Chipset)
MB: Biostar TA770 A2+ (Chipset AMD 770)
```

Please let me know, if you need any further information.

Comment: I am very sure Ubuntu uses fan control as well. You could just copy the configuration file. Ubuntu uses a much more recent kernel than Debian, maybe the default Debian kernel simply doesn't have the drivers and if you upgraded to a more recent kernel fancontrol might just start working for you.

Comment: Oh.. well.. I could've had the idea of just copying the file as well.. Thank you, I'll try it and let you know if everything is fine then.. (actually I don't think it's a thing of the kernel, because I am using Ubuntu 12.04, which supports the case fan and Fedora (also a more recent kernel I guess) does not just like Debian..)

Comment: so.. I just tried to do so, but there was now way of finding wether /etc/fancontrol or /etc/sensors.conf . Both seem not to exist in Ubuntu, so it could be possible Ubuntu is using other tools or is just saving the configs somewhere else?

Comment: Boot into Ubuntu, open a shell and, when after Ubuntu has regulated your fan speeds, look at the process list (`man ps`) and see if fancontrol is running. If it is, `lsof` may tell you where the configurations are at. Also try running `sudo sensors-detect` in that shell and see if Ubuntu finds your fans. As 12.04 is a long term release I guess they'll be backporting drivers into its kernel.

Comment: Just did so: No way. There's definitely no instance of fancontrol running when Ubuntu is booted. So, is there any other way to control the speed of those fans? (Also 'sensors-detect' seems not to exist, therefore fancontrol is probably not even installed.)

Comment: Technically `sensors-detect` is not part of `fancontrol`, I think. i'm sorry, I don't know what else Ubuntu may be using. There is a program called `sensors`, but I don't know where it belongs to nor what it can do.